# obj file loaded as Scene object instead of Trimesh object

Tags: python, trimesh

I'm trying to load a mesh from an .obj file (from ShapeNet dataset) using Trimesh, and then use the `repair.fix_winding(mesh)` function.

But when I load the mesh, via

`trimesh.load('/path/to/file.obj')` or `trimesh.load_mesh('/path/to/file.obj')`,

the object class returned is Scene, which is incompatible with `repair.fix_winding(mesh)`, only Trimesh object are accepted.

How can I force it to load and return a Trimesh object or parse the Scene object to Trimesh object? Or any other way to fix winding of the triangles?

Using:

Python 3.6.5

Trimesh 3.0.14

MacOS 10.14.5

Answer (score 2):

With the current trimesh version (3.9.42), you need to use `trimesh.load` with `force='mesh'`:

```
trimesh.load('/path/to/file.obj', force='mesh')
```

https://trimsh.org/trimesh.html?highlight=load#trimesh.load

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. You can access the "geometry" member of the scene, but I have no idea how the original mesh is split into multiple ones. Following.

Answer (score 0):

The load_mesh has an option to be passed as aa Trimesh constructor
as explained in the documentation.

https://trimsh.org/trimesh.html?highlight=load_mesh#trimesh.load_mesh

here is an example code

```py
mesh= t.load_mesh('./test.stl',process=False)
mesh.is_watertight
```

the second line ".is_watertight" is an attribute of Trimesh so you will get True if it is successfully imported as Trimesh.